# Email notifications on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

So, I have this website that I've built http://leapfm.com/ and more and more users are joining which is fantastic. I've noticed that users sign back on to check if their song has been up-voted. I'd like to automate this process for them.

So, I'd like to implement a feature that sends the user an email when their song is up-voted. I'm not sure if this is possible with my stack specifically.

E.g. for up voting I'm using [this gem](https://www.github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up).

Can I implement somethin' like this? If you need me to provide any additional information, don't be afraid to ask.

song_controller snippit (create action):

```
def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)
    @song.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.save
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @song }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What about a combination of Rails Mailer and the delayed job gem?

Comment: You seem to want to mention a gem you use for voting?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post with the gem. And Mindbreaker I'll look into that, thanks!

Comment: Seconded on delayed_job. You're definitely going to want to kick off jobs to do something like this, so it won't delay the particular HTTP request/response that triggers the email.

Comment: Agreed, delayed_job seems like the right tool to keep things running smoothly. Albeit, writing the code for the send action seems a little confusing..e.g in plain english: when 'User A' up-votes 'User Bs' song send email notification to 'User B'. Now how would I translate this into code?

Comment: I'm thinking a line like UserMailer.up_vote(@song.user).deliver in the song_controller ? I've updated post with current song controller create action

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be fairly straightforward. What you would want to do is send an email each time a vote record is created.
First, within your Vote model, you would set up an `after_commit` handler when an instance is created.

```
class Vote
  ...
  after_commit :send_email, :on => :create

  def send_email
    # send the email to whoever owns votable
  end
end
```

Within the `# send the email` part, there are several options. The simplest would be to simply configure ActionMailer and deliver emails within that `send_email` method. There are several methods for setting this up. The one I most recently used was [Postmark](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-libs.html#rails-gem), for which you would install `postmark-rails` and add something like the following to your `config/environments/production.rb`.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => 'your-api-key' }
```

However, I encourage you to check out the various providers to find one that fits your needs (I can think of Postmark, SendGrid, Mailgun).

Then, run `rails generate mailer VoteMailer`, which will create a VoteMailer class under `app/mailers/vote_mailer.rb`. Edit it to fit your needs.

```
class VoteMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def vote_notification(voter, song)
    @voter = voter
    @song = song
    @user = @song.user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Someone voted on your song!')
  end
end
```

Now, you create a template in `app/views/vote_mailer/vote_notification.text.erb`.

```
Hey <%= @user.name %>,

Someone voted on your song, <%= @song.name %>!

Congrats!
```

Then, use the mailer in your `send_email` method.

```
class Vote
  ...
  def send_email
    VoteNotifier.vote_notification(voter, voteable).deliver!
  end
end
```

This should get you started.

People were commenting earlier about needing to use Delayed Job. This is because sending email can be a slow process. If every time a user clicks 'upvote', they have to wait 5 seconds while the email is sent, they will become dissatisfied with the service.

To avoid this problem, people will take the more time consuming parts of their server request and stick them into a job queue, which will be processed by another server. To achieve this with your emails, you would install [`delayed_job_active_record`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record) and change your `send_email` method:

```
class Vote
  ...
  def send_email
    VoteNotifier.delay.vote_notification(voter, voteable)
  end
end
```

And then in a separate process on your server, run the `jobs:work` Rake task.

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

This process should be running 24/7, just like your web server process.

Comment: thank you Benjamin, looking forward to the Delayed job part - this is fantastic!

Comment: I just updated it. Feel free to ask if you have any more questions.